# Why to avoid this.setState(this.state)?

Tags: reactjs

In React, I tried both:

- change the state then this.setState(this.state)
- clone the state, change the state clone, then this.setState(stateClone)

they both work and both produce the same results. Why is it suggested (in the docs) to set to the state clone (with Object.assign) instead of setting to the state itself? Does the object identity of the state matters in React(without Redux)? It seems like as long as you call setState, the render() will get triggered anyway regardless of the state object identity.

Comment: i think if you declare a shouldComponentUpdate method, you can’t use a === equality check inside because the object reference will not change. So your approach will have a potential performance impact as well

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, so I actually posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState doesn't care if the object you set has the same reference as the current state. render() will be called either way.

Immutability is useful only for shallow checking (using === to compare before and after) in the context of optimization with the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method, which by default returns true.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript objects and arrays are passed through reference and not value, when we say

`stateClone = this.state`

we’re not making a copy of the state object,  we are just creating a new reference to the same object (this.state). Now, if we make any changes to stateClone like

`stateClone.someProp = someValue`

we actually mutate the original state directly, which is prohibited since mutations made this way might be overridden on the next `setState` call.

That is why, `Object.assign` or `spread operator (...)` is used to create a copy of the state object and changes are made to that copy.

More info: https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

Comment: I read the article, still not sure why mutating the object directly is dangerous (it says what you said basically), and why "might be overriden on the next setState call" is a concern.

Comment: Terminology correction: `stateClone = this.state` doesn't create a new *reference*. Rather it will create a new variable/property stateClone and both points to same reference/memory location.